# Programmatically retrieving Document ID

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, document-id, graph-api

I have a SharePoint Online site collection with Document ID service enabled, so that every document uploaded to a document library in the site has a unique document identifier. All the documents will be uploaded via a custom web application using the Graph API and the Document ID of an uploaded document needs to be stored in an Azure SQL database for. While I am able to upload a document of less than 4 MB in size  using the PUT request following this guide (https://rahul-metangale.medium.com/upload-a-file-to-sharepoint-using-azure-graph-api-9deacce57449), I am not getting the Document ID of the uploaded document in the response body or response header. Nor did I find a way to get the Document ID of the recently uploaded document using a Graph API. Is there a way I can retrieve the Document ID of the uploaded document, either in the response of the PUT request for upload or via a separate Graph API call immediately after the document is uploaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- After uploading the file using graph api you will get **drive item id**.
- Use **drive item id** to retrieve list item (If resource type is SharePoint)
- Upload file to SharePoint library using below api

```
PUT  /v1.0/sites/{{SPSiteID}}/drives/{{DriveID}}/root:/FolderA/FileB11.txt:/content

Content-Type: text/plain

The contents of the file goes here.
```

- Sample Response

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "id": "0123456789abc",
  "name": "FileB11.txt",
  "size": 35,
  "file": { }
}
```

- Use id at place of {itemId} to retrieve listitem

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/drive/items/{itemId}/listItem?expand=fields
```

- Sample Response body

[image: Upload File]

```
 "fields": {
        "@odata.etag": "\"e0f74957-7857-4870-9786-a57a1638afc5,1\"",
        "FileLeafRef": "FileB11.txt",
        "_dlc_DocIdUrl": {
            "Description": "DH4H5HF5VT36-803088927-3",
            "Url": "https://missiono365.sharepoint.com/sites/PermissionDemo/_layouts/15/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=DH4H5HF5VT36-803088927-3"
        },
        "id": "3",
        "ContentType": "Document",
        "Created": "2022-03-09T05:13:13Z",
        "AuthorLookupId": "6",
        "Modified": "2022-03-09T05:13:13Z",
        "EditorLookupId": "6",
        "_CheckinComment": "",
        "LinkFilenameNoMenu": "FileB11.txt",
        "LinkFilename": "FileB11.txt",
        "DocIcon": "txt",
        "FileSizeDisplay": "17",
        "ItemChildCount": "0",
        "FolderChildCount": "0",
        "_ComplianceFlags": "",
        "_ComplianceTag": "",
        "_ComplianceTagWrittenTime": "",
        "_ComplianceTagUserId": "",
        "_CommentCount": "",
        "_LikeCount": "",
        "_DisplayName": "",
        "AppAuthorLookupId": "8",
        "AppEditorLookupId": "8",
        "Edit": "0",
        "_UIVersionString": "1.0",
        "ParentVersionStringLookupId": "3",
        "ParentLeafNameLookupId": "3"
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! A follow-up question if you can help with:  if user does a bulk upload of documents and I retrieve the Document IDs of all those documents using the above approach, is there a Graph API which I can subsequently invoke to filter documents based on those multiple Document IDs and return the matching documents back?

Comment: use graph api batch request for that.